# Redirect with the original title and description

Tags: php, html, apache, redirect

I need to redirect a page whilst keeping the original page (not the one redirected to) share title and description and icon.

So in this example, the share preview in Whatsapp etc would say Title rather than Google.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Download now">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png">
  <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

</head>

<body>
  <?php
  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
  header("Location: google.com");
  ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That is not possible, not with the redirect.

Comment: You can set titles for bit.ly links though no? How have they done it.

Comment: can you share a bit.ly example?

Comment: Hmm I think I'm mistaken! Yeah so there's definitely no work around this :( even with a different type of redirect?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is some kind of iframe or reverse proxy. But that would still show your domain name in client's address bar.

Comment: Reverse proxy, that would keep all.  If you want to keep only the title and icon, I see no way...